# Посоветуйте компилятор для c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Всем привет, не могли бы вы посоветовать компилятор для c#, кроме Visual Studio, ибо там работать не очень нравится, и желательно другие компиляторы от Microsoft,не советовать, хотя если знаете то говорите.

Comment: Visual Studio не компилятор, а IDE

Comment: Ищите не компилятор, а рабочую среду. (в данном случае вы, вероятнее всего, говорите именно про неё).

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Чтобы посоветовать замену Визуал Студии, нужно знать, чем она вам не понравилась. Вдруг мы посоветуем такую IDE, которая имеет те же самые недостатки, критичные для вас.

Comment: райдер, моно...грузит меньше под линуксом дружелюбно пускается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы всё таки про IDE, то я бы как альтернативой бы вам посоветовал **Rider** от **JetBrains**, сам честно не пользовался, но пользовался другими IDE от JetBrains : Clion, Intellij, Goland и PyCharm и остался рад, так что хотя-бы попробуйте.

Плюсы (сразу заметны новичкам):

> - Поддерживается Windows, Mac, Linux
> - Хорошие "smart" подсказки
> - Рефакторинг
> - Поддержка систем управления версиями (git например)

Минусы:

> - Платный

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Так же есть от Microsoft **Visual Studio Code**, тут всё бесплатно и достаточно для старта новичку. Тут есть всё необходимое, IntelliSense (автодополнение), рефакторинг, отладка, поддержка git и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вродебы нет поддержки для отладки Razor и форматирования в vs code